# IE 11:active CSS selector blocked by child elements and :active CSS selector siblings are not selected

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

1. span element inside a div element.
2. div's Background color will be changed by clicking either on div or span.
3. This is working in all browsers except IE11. 
   Please find the code snippet for this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>IE11 :active issue</title>
    <style>
        .parent {}
        
        .child {
            width: 100px;
            pointer-events: none;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        
        .parent:active {
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        .child:active {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <span class="child">Click Me</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*please suggest me any work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display: inline-block` on the child element, you can force IE11 to recognize the `pointer-events: none` set on it. Also, you should be using it anyway: `<span>` is an inline element by default and you cannot define explicit width (in this case, `100px`) on them.

```css
.parent {}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.parent:active {
  background-color: red;
}

.child:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">Click Me</span>
</div>
```